# Bootstrap drop down menu appears below Flexslider in IE7

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

[image]The drop down menu (When you move mouse over LOGIN link on the right) appears proper in all browsers except IE7.

In IE 7, it appears below the Sliding Images creating using FlexSlider plugin.

http://www.dreamsmedia.org/ajmat/index.html

Comment: here it is, http://www.dreamsmedia.org/ajmat/index.html, accidently clicked on submit before posting.

Comment: I guess others are facing issues with FlexSlider on IE7, see the github posted issue https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/195

Comment: Hey AurA, actually the flexslider is working fine. Am just having trouble with the menu being displayed below the flex slider.

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is very late but if anyone has the same problem !!

Try this : 
`.slidercontainer {position:absolute; z-index: -1000}`

Answer (score 0):

Add a z-index to the nav bar container div of the login-form.  For example, using inline CSS:

```
<div class="nav_block container" style="z-index: 1000;">
  ...
    <div class="dropdown-menu ie7 pull-right" id="login-form" aria-labelledby="login-form">
```

In this case the z-index is only relevant to its parent, so adding a z-index to the login-form div will not fix the issue.  This is due to the div stacking context.  More information on stacking context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context

Comment: z-index resolved the issue for me in all browsers I tested, including IE7.

Comment: Did you try it in my code above? or you meant your own website?

Comment: Please see another link in my original question. It has he screenshot after adding the z-index.

Comment: Once you add the z-index; please hit F12 in your browser to bring up developer tools, then find the login-form div and confirm the z-index is present and active.

Comment: Hello,Yes I do confirm that I have checked this. You can see it for yourself at http://www.dreamsmedia.org/ajmat/index.html. Like I said more than the menu the issue might be caused due to the Flex slider.

Comment: Try adding a z-index to the navbar container: `<div class="nav_block container" style="z-index: 1000;">`  I've updated my answer to reflect this suggestion.